# IE not caching static content

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, webforms, web-config

We have a .NET 3.5 WebForms Application and have an issue with client caching. Internet explorer (Tried on IE11) refuses to cache any static content such as css, js or images. However, it works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox. The response header on Firefox and Chrome is max-age=604800 while on IE is no-cache,max-age=604800. Due to this reason, the status is 200 on IE and 304 on all others.

Caching has been configured on IIS in multiple ways:

- Output Caching on IIS: Created two new items (one for CSS and one for JS). Both are configured to cache until change.
- HTTP Response Headers - Expire Web content after 7 days
- web.config:

  <staticContent>
   <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>

But none of them seem to have any effect on IE. I assume that the added no-cache is the reason of the issue. How would I get rid of it on IE to enforce caching of static content?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you read this article?
http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2011/10/internet-explorer-static-file-caching-defect/

Comment: Yes, but doesn't explain my issue. This one describes the issue of time but mine is already in GMT. And the article exclusively says that their issue didn't have the no-cache but mine has it and I am wondering how to remove this in IE (Since it does not appear in others)

Answer (score 0):

[This link talks specifically about this issue](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/15/two-important-differences-between-firefox-and-ie-caching/) - it describes the difference between the Firefox and IE and caching.

In short you correct - IE respects the "no-cache" and Firefox ignores it.

I hope this helps!